# Solving a second order differential equation related to circles

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have $ry''=[1+(y')^2]^{3/2}$, and I have to obtain $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$, where y=y(x). Edit: r is constant

So I first let $v=y'$, and I substitute it in to obtain

$r\frac{dv}{dx}=(1+v^2)^{3/2}$, which is variable separable, so I get

$\frac{rdv}{(1+v^2)^{3/2}}=dx$, integrate both sides (left hand trig sub, v=tana), and I obtain

$\frac{rv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}=x+C$, and I isolate v, then substitute back in dy/dx to get

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+C}{\sqrt{r-(x+C)^2}}$, and this is where I get stuck.  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: It looks to me that $r$ in your LHS depends on both $x$ and $y$, right? So, effectively, you have not separated the variables.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that it says r is constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for $\sqrt{r - (x+C)^2}$  to make sense we need $-\sqrt r \le (x+C) \le \sqrt r.$ so we make the substitution $$x+C = \sqrt r \sin t. \tag 1$$
 that gives $dx = \sqrt r \cos t \,dt$
  so the differential equation is 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt r \cos t}\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{\sqrt r \sin t}{\sqrt r \cos t}$$ and the solution is $$ y = \sqrt r \cos t - B \tag 2$$

eliminating $t$ from $(1)$ and $(2),$  we get $$(x+C)^2 + (y+B)^2 = r$$

Comment: Wow what an answer!  Thanks!  Some tricky stuff here have to keep it in mind